# Mesh and FrameTicks are incompatible options for ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting

Adding the option `Mesh->True` to an `ArrayPlot` stops the `FrameTicks` from appearing. Why? How do I fix?

```
array = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];
ArrayPlot[array, FrameTicks -> All]
ArrayPlot[array, FrameTicks -> All, Mesh -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the option `Frame->True`:

```
ArrayPlot[array, FrameTicks -> All, Frame -> True, Mesh -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: What a simple fix. Thanks :)